# java code to find response time of a webpage without using selenium and apache

Tags: java, selenium

i have written a code to find the response time of a web page but it always
give 0 time .can someone plz complete this code to get the response time

**mycode**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
public class NewClass {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    URL myURL = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/");


    long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalTime = finish - start; 

    System.out.println("Total Time for page load - "+totalTime);

 }

}
```

Comment: You are measuring the object instantiation time. Which code is hitting this URL?

Comment: You only create an object of URL. You never call this

Comment: can you upload the code for that

Comment: Whats plz are you afraid of please and spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
       try {
                URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                String jsonResponse = myInputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());

                long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long totalTime = finish - start;
                System.out.println("Total Time for page load - " + totalTime);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                connection.disconnect();
            }

    static public String myInputStreamReader(InputStream in) throws IOException {

            StringBuilder sb = null;
            try {
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                int c = reader.read();
                while (c != -1) {
                    sb.append((char) c);
                    c = reader.read();
                }
                reader.close();
                return sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
```

Comment: here you have used apache,but I need only with java library functions

Comment: @AdeelAhmed You have used the `connect` method which "Opens a communications link to the resource referenced by this URL, if such a connection has not already been established" **but** "If the connect method is called when the connection has already been opened (indicated by the connected field having the value true), the call is ignored.". This URLConnection objects go through two phases: first they are created, then they are connected **and** have no relation with "response time of a web page" what OP is asking for. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB
in your answer you are using Chrome Driver but OP says he needs it with only java library not with any external program

Comment: @DebanjanB how about now ? now i am fetching the html from it

Comment: seems you haven't defined `connection`. Thanks

Comment: You seem to be doing just `connection.getInputStream()` between `start` and `finish`, how do I confirm if the response is there or not? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

You can find the response time of a webpage even without using selenium and apache through the `java.net.URL` and `java.net.HttpURLConnection` classes as follows-

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Q44304154_response_time_of_webpage_2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    long start = 0;
    long finish = 0;
    String stack_url = "https://stackoverflow.com/";

    try {
        URL url = new URL(stack_url);
        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpUrlConnect.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        httpUrlConnect.connect();

        if (httpUrlConnect.getResponseCode() == 200) 
        {
            finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(stack_url + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage() + " took " + (finish-start) + " Milli Seconds.");
        }

        if (httpUrlConnect.getResponseCode() == httpUrlConnect.HTTP_NOT_FOUND) 
        {
            System.out.println(
                    stack_url + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage() + " - " + httpUrlConnect.HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        } 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {

    }

    System.out.println("Total Time for page load - "+ (finish-start));

 }


}
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: and I want to know if I want to take this response time once a minute to where should I set the timer

Comment: @mahi Glad to be able to help you. You can always `take this response time once a minute` through `netbeans` putting this code block in a loop as it is pure Java code but in that case you may consider showing us your work. Feel free to raise a new Question with your new requirement. Thanks

Comment: I'm not downvoter, but your code do not fetch page content, and measure only initial response time. And that strange pick only 2 HTTP response codes and completely ignoring rest. And exception sink (if connect timeout happens, your code print negative time). And total page load time is wrong. Maybe as response time it is OK, but not as total page load.

Comment: @user1516873 Can you consider coming out with your new requirement and frame a new Question please. I think OP's requirement was different than yours. Thanks

Comment: why should i do it? You ask why you get downvote, i give you 3 possible reasons, i don't want to write any requirements, thank you.

Comment: This question have no relation to page contents or loading of page contents. It simply establishes a connection and returns the status. Thanks

Comment: it's also worth noting, this is "not" using selenium, but rather plain ol' java.  i'm +1'ing this answer because Selenium is superfluous to this sort of task.

Comment: @sircapsalot Thanks, my answer was based on the fact that OP was looking for an Answer without using Selenium & Apache POI. Thanks