# How to get output to a file using java?

Tags: java

I have written a java code to print my output in a file which is located in documents but after executing the code file is still empty.Can someone make my mistake.I am using netbeans to create this program

**code**

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class NewClass1 {

    static long start = 0;
    static long finish = 0;
    static long time;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {

            String stack_url = "https://www.google.lk/";

            try {
                URL url = new URL(stack_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpUrlConnect.setConnectTimeout(10);
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                httpUrlConnect.connect();

                if (httpUrlConnect.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    System.out.println(stack_url + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage() + " took " + (finish - start) + " Milli Seconds.");
                }

                if (httpUrlConnect.getResponseCode() == httpUrlConnect.HTTP_NOT_FOUND) {
                    System.out.println(stack_url + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage() + " - " + httpUrlConnect.HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            time = finish - start;
            finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Total Time for page load - " + (finish - start));

            try {

                Integer _time = (int) (long) time;
                String content = Integer.toString(_time);
                fw = new FileWriter("time.sql");
                bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write(content);

                System.out.println("Done");

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {

                try {

                    if (bw != null) {
                        bw.close();
                    }

                    if (fw != null) {
                        fw.close();
                    }

                } catch (IOException ex) {

                    ex.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: **Never**  write`} catch (Exception e) {

            }`. Always handle exceptions. atleast logg the stacktrace

Comment: I guess you get an exception. by reading a URL. in this case an empty file will be created

Comment: Also you create the file in a Loop, so in every execution the file will be overridden

Comment: i tried it also bt still not showing output

Comment: *i tried it also* What is it?

Comment: You have very small timelimit for timeout. It took around `861 ms` for my connection to get response and you have set it `10 ms`. May be you connection speed is not that high to get result in `10` ms. You need to increase the timelimit. You can increase it by `1s = 1000ms` It may solve your problem if your connection get response in `1000ms`. If you print the `stackTrace` you will come to know about this error more.

Comment: @YCF_L I saw it just after adding the comment. Your answer is correct but It is not advisable to remove that statement as Program may take infinte time to terminate if connection is not available. OP should increase the time limit and that will be the only perfect solution.

Comment: @Jens It is partially adopted code, bad exception handling copy-pasted from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44305565

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use try-with-resource like:

```
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("D:\\time.sql"))
```

as the first line in your main method and in you finally block and you can remove `fw.close()` 
call.

If you wish you can directly use `fw.write(content);` instead of a buffered writer.

you can get rid of the following code (as you are looping and everytime a new object is constructed which is not required) if you use the try with resource:

```
fw = new FileWriter("time.sql");
bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(content);
```

and instead use:

```
fw.write(content);
```

I did make the above changes and it works for me.

HTH,
AJ

Answer (score 1):

**First thing :**

Your program don't take the full time to be executed so instead you have to increase the time :

```
httpUrlConnect.setConnectTimeout(1000);
//--------------------------------^^
```

---

**Second thing :**

Don't create your file inside your code, just create it before so you have to move this two line outside your loop :

```
fw = new FileWriter("time.sql");
bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
```

**Third thing :**

Don't close your files in each iteration, close it when you finish so you have to remove finally block and close your file after your loop.

```
bw.close();
fw.close();
```

---

Your code should look like this :

**EDITED by user1516873**

```
@Test
public void test44325932() {

    final String stackUrl = "https://www.google.lk/";

    // BufferedWriter is closable, it will close automatically (and close underline stream) in finally block
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("time.sql"))) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            String responseStatus;
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long finish;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(stackUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setConnectTimeout(5000); // 5 sec connect timeout
                connection.connect();
                if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    responseStatus = "OK";
                } else { // any non 200 status counts as error
                    responseStatus = connection.getResponseCode() + " : " + connection.getResponseMessage();
                }
                // full time should be calculated after completely reading response, not after get status code, but it is depends of requirements
                // I put it here as example
                // IOUtils.readFully(connection.getInputStream(), new byte[1024]);
                connection.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {                   
                responseStatus = "Exception : " + e.getClass().getSimpleName();
            } finally {
                finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }

            long time = finish - start;
            System.out.println("Server response: " + time + " ms, status: " + responseStatus);
            bw.write(String.valueOf(time)); // i think you should write status here, too.
            bw.newLine();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```